# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT unless i've rebooted my router in the last few hours

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

I'm attempting to connect to a specific website, e43.ultipro.com, and am getting the following error. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in chrome, edge and brave, including private/incognito windows and on my android phone while connected to wifi.

If I restart my router, it works for a few hours, but reverts to not working again.

When it's not working, i can nslookup and resolve the IP, but I still can't connect. I've tried flushing my dns as well.

```
nslookup e43.ultipro.com
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    e43.ultipro.com
Address:  135.84.64.154
```

Changing my DNS doesn't help.

Seems like my ISP is dns blackholing my requests? They do the same thing with some piracy websites, but those don't start working after a reboot.

Comment: Which router? Are you using the latest firmware?

Comment: perhaps `e43.ultipro.com` itself is blocking you

Comment: It could be a connection tracking issue with your router

Comment: Note that ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT indicates that the issue is not a name lookup problem, but simply that no response was received when attempting to connect to the IP. This usually implies a firewall is intervening, but could be caused by the webserver malfunctioning (or some form of WAF or request filtering). is your public IP the same across router reboots?

Comment: @davidgo not sure how to check that and googling it doesn't really return anything.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Whatever the default VZW lte router is. ASK-NCQ1338 according to the software. I can't manually push an update or even check for one.

Comment: @JaromandaX that's possible but I'm not sure why they would do that, and I'm not sure why rebooting the router would fix it.

Comment: @FrankThomas sorry, not sure how to check that.

Comment: oh, true, hadn't thought of that - unless it is an IP change like Frank Thomas mentioned - you check that in your router

Comment: easiest way I know to check public IP, is to type "whats my public IP" into google.